# {"error":"missing required parameter \"q\""}

Tags: python, python-3.x, influxdb

Am trying for days to pull some date from influxDB and am getting the below missing parameter "q" with 400 error or if i change something in the parameters am getting 404 error on the response
if anyone faced the same issue on the past or someone to help to understand how can i resolve this issue?

```
url='https://<hostname>8086/query'
values=[] 
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}
params = {
'db': 'tail_screw_20',
}
data = 'q=select time, "RH(%)", "T(C)" from PM_histo WHERE time >= \'2022-05-04T11:00:00Z\' 
and time <= \'2022-05-04T11:10:00Z\' order by time asc'
response = requests.get(url=url, params=params, headers=headers,verify=False,data=data)
print(response.text)
print(response)
```

**Error:**

**{"error":"missing required parameter "q""}
<Response [400]>**

Editing the Query:

```
url='https://<localHost>:8086/query?db=tail_screw_20'
client = influxdb_client.InfluxDBClient(
     url=url,
    token='None',
    ssl=False, 
    verify_ssl=False,
   
)

query_api = client.query_api()
result = query_api.query('''
        from(bucket:"PM_histo") |> range(start: _start)
            |> filter(fn: (r) => r["time"] == "time")
            |> filter(fn: (r) => r["RH(%)"] == "RH(%)")
            |> filter(fn: (r) => r["T(C)"] == "T(C)")       
            |> sort(columns: ["_time"], desc: _asc) 
    ''')

resultsA = query_api.query_csv(query=result)
print(resultsA)
```

**error:**

HTTP response body: b'{"error":"missing required parameter \"q\""}\n'

Answer (score 1):

this issue usually is related to a problem to the parameter you pass with data=data.

Please check the data variable, should it be a tuple/ditctionary?
https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: Hello thank you for your feedback - i tried to make the query like this but still getting error.. any idea how can i resolve this as am stuck :( Editing above